# All elements in Electron app are scaled down in dev environment but appear normal in production build

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I've been having this issue across **all** of my Electron apps where my development environment seems to scale down all elements in my application by some factor. Things appear completely normal when I create a production build of the application.

[Side by side comparison of dev and prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eiyO.png)

I'm using [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) as my starting project for all of my Electron apps, and my machine is a 2019 i7 MacBook Pro.

I don't believe it's appropriate to include the code for any elements in the renderer process considering this isn't occurring in the production build.

This appears to also be a macOS specific issue as the dev environment looks normal on my Windows machine.

package.json

```json
{
  "description": "A foundation for scalable desktop apps",
  "keywords": [
    "electron",
    "boilerplate",
    "react",
    "typescript",
    "ts",
    "sass",
    "webpack",
    "hot",
    "reload"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate#readme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Electron React Boilerplate Maintainers",
    "email": "electronreactboilerplate@gmail.com",
    "url": "https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Amila Welihinda",
      "email": "amilajack@gmail.com",
      "url": "https://github.com/amilajack"
    }
  ],
  "main": "./src/main/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run build:main\" \"npm run build:renderer\"",
    "build:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.main.prod.ts",
    "build:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.prod.ts",
    "postinstall": "ts-node .erb/scripts/check-native-dep.js && electron-builder install-app-deps && cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.ts",
    "lint": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "package": "ts-node ./.erb/scripts/clean.js dist && npm run build && electron-builder build --publish never",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild --parallel --types prod,dev,optional --module-dir release/app",
    "start": "ts-node ./.erb/scripts/check-port-in-use.js && npm run start:renderer",
    "start:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electronmon -r ts-node/register/transpile-only .",
    "start:preload": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.preload.dev.ts",
    "start:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack serve --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.ts",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "browserslist": [],
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          ".prettierrc",
          ".eslintrc"
        ],
        "options": {
          "parser": "json"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "release/app/node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/.erb/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./.erb/scripts/check-build-exists.ts"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "url": "http://localhost/"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "release/app/dist",
      ".erb/dll"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.0",
    "electron-debug": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.8",
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron/notarize": "^1.2.3",
    "@electron/rebuild": "^3.2.10",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.10",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^2.5.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.51.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.51.0",
    "browserslist-config-erb": "^0.0.3",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.27.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "detect-port": "^1.5.1",
    "electron": "^23.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-erb": "^4.0.6",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.2",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "ElectronReact",
    "appId": "org.erb.ElectronReact",
    "asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": "**\\*.{node,dll}",
    "files": [
      "dist",
      "node_modules",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "afterSign": ".erb/scripts/notarize.js",
    "mac": {
      "target": {
        "target": "default",
        "arch": [
          "arm64",
          "x64"
        ]
      },
      "type": "distribution",
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "gatekeeperAssess": false
    },
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "category": "Development"
    },
    "directories": {
      "app": "release/app",
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "release/build"
    },
    "extraResources": [
      "./assets/**"
    ],
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github",
      "owner": "electron-react-boilerplate",
      "repo": "electron-react-boilerplate"
    }
  },
  "collective": {
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/electron-react-boilerplate-594"
  },
  "devEngines": {
    "node": ">=14.x",
    "npm": ">=7.x"
  },
  "electronmon": {
    "patterns": [
      "!**/**",
      "src/main/**"
    ],
    "logLevel": "quiet"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```js
/* eslint global-require: off, no-console: off, promise/always-return: off */

/**
 * This module executes inside of electron's main process. You can start
 * electron renderer process from here and communicate with the other processes
 * through IPC.
 *
 * When running `npm run build` or `npm run build:main`, this file is compiled to
 * `./src/main.js` using webpack. This gives us some performance wins.
 */
import path from 'path';
import { app, BrowserWindow, shell, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
import log from 'electron-log';
import MenuBuilder from './menu';
import { resolveHtmlPath } from './util';

class AppUpdater {
  constructor() {
    log.transports.file.level = 'info';
    autoUpdater.logger = log;
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
  }
}

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

ipcMain.on('ipc-example', async (event, arg) => {
  const msgTemplate = (pingPong: string) => `IPC test: ${pingPong}`;
  console.log(msgTemplate(arg));
  event.reply('ipc-example', msgTemplate('pong'));
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const sourceMapSupport = require('source-map-support');
  sourceMapSupport.install();
}

const isDebug =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true';

if (isDebug) {
  require('electron-debug')();
}

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const installer = require('electron-devtools-installer');
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = ['REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS'];

  return installer
    .default(
      extensions.map((name) => installer[name]),
      forceDownload
    )
    .catch(console.log);
};

const createWindow = async () => {
  if (isDebug) {
    await installExtensions();
  }

  const RESOURCES_PATH = app.isPackaged
    ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'assets')
    : path.join(__dirname, '../../assets');

  const getAssetPath = (...paths: string[]): string => {
    return path.join(RESOURCES_PATH, ...paths);
  };

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: app.isPackaged
        ? path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        : path.join(__dirname, '../../.erb/dll/preload.js'),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath('index.html'));

  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
      throw new Error('"mainWindow" is not defined');
    }
    if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
      mainWindow.minimize();
    } else {
      mainWindow.show();
    }
  });

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  const menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(mainWindow);
  menuBuilder.buildMenu();

  // Open urls in the user's browser
  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((edata) => {
    shell.openExternal(edata.url);
    return { action: 'deny' };
  });

  // Remove this if your app does not use auto updates
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  new AppUpdater();
};

/**
 * Add event listeners...
 */

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // Respect the OSX convention of having the application in memory even
  // after all windows have been closed
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app
  .whenReady()
  .then(() => {
    createWindow();
    app.on('activate', () => {
      // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
      // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
      if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
    });
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: have you tryed running this code on any other pc or OS?

Comment: Yep, things appear completely normal on my Windows machine. I failed to mention that, definitely an important detail.

Comment: Perhaps this have something related to `/build/dmg/contents`, take a look [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/dmg.html) into `contents` and `window` props.